# How do you get resources working in app/service1 from app/service2 behind SSO

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, big-ip

I have very limited knowledge on how SSO works behind the curtains, let alone its configuration.
I am working on a server that is protected by SSO(Single sign-on). On this server i have multiple sub-domains that have independent apps and services.
Some of them have APIs available. I am trying to build a website/mashup where i access these APIs. Would that be possible?

Thanks in advance

I don't know if it's a server policy but right now, if i:
Visit mywebsite.domain.com -> Redirect to Identity provider -> Redirect back to mywebsite.domain.com.
On this website i can't reach the APIs because the calls get intercepted by the iP.

Answer (score 2):

The question here is very generic and lacks details. But I will try to answer based on what I understand.

So, your web app is registered with the Identity provider and thats's the reason you are getting authenticated successfully. While you are getting redirected back to the website check if  you see any kind of token or auth_code in the response. If not then you have to find out how you can get the access token from the auth server.

In general scenarios, you would require to pass this access token in the authorization header for the api calls. The header would look something like this: 
Authorization: Bearer

That should be all that you need to do to access the service.

Comment: We have multiple subdomains that are housing apps and services. Normally you would access one of them, get redirected to either login or for the iP validates your session and get ported back to the subdomain you wanted.
The issue is getting resources on one subdomain that are hosted on a second subdomain. All get requests will be met (at least in the first time accessing) with the iP redirect, if i try to grab the API from the second one.

Thanks for the swift response and help so far!